# Regarding the Global vs. Local Variables Examples from Daniel Shiffman's "Learning Processing"

Tags: variables, colors, processing

Included in the native examples for Processing are the following two from Daniel Shiffman's "Learning Processing:"

Example #1

---

```
void setup() {
  size(200,200);
}

void draw() {
  int count = 0;
  count = count + 1;
  background(count);
}
```

Example #2

---

```
int count = 0;

void setup() {
  size(200,200);
}

void draw() {
  count = count + 1;
  background(count);
}
```

The question that I would pose for the first example is likely one that has already been asked; my best guess is that the local variable doesn't work in this instance because `draw()` is a loop, and so even if the statement `count = count + 1` exists to enumerate `int count`, declaring `int count = 0` within the `draw()` loop means that the value is constantly reset zero. Is this correct?

As for the second example, the question is not necessarily about the variable so much as it is about the way that the program runs: After the first loop, which goes from black to white, why does the program then continue to cycle through from black to blue? How can this be avoided or fixed in other applications?

Answer (score 1):

Int he first example the variable is declared in the scope `drew`. Every time when `draw` is invoked, then variable `count` is created and initialized by 0.

In the 2nd example the global variable `count` is use. The variable is initialized once  at startup of the application and is incremented continuously.

If the argument to [`background()`] can be a integral value in range [0, 255]. In this case the argument is interpreted as grayscale, where 0 is black and 255 is white.
It the integral value is greater than 255, it is interpreted as ans RGB value wich consist of 3 8bit color components (0xRRGGBB). 0xff0000 is red, 0x00ff00 is green and 0x0000ff would be blue.

To a void that the color turns in blue, you have to ensure that the value is smaller then 255. e.g:

```java
void draw() {
    count = count + 1;
    if (count > 255) {
        count = 0;
    }
    background(count);
}
```

Comment: To be sure that I understand correctly, what you're saying is that a statement like `background(256);` is interpreted as an RGB value. If that is the case, how does the integer value being one higher than 255 shift the count over to blue specifically as `background(0, 0, [0, 255]);`? If that value spills from greyscale into RGB, because red is the first argument in `background()`, why doesn't the loop shift to red instead of blue?

Comment: @NicholasHoyt You are right. Nothing is shifted. 255 is 0x000ff and 256 is 0x000100. So 256 in fact is RGB(0,1,0) that is almost black just a bit green. 511 is 0x0001ff that is RGB(0,1,255). Note, shifting is implicitly, it is just an integral number. The lower 8 bits are blue, bit 9 to 16 are green and bits 17 to 24 are red.